# How to determine the date a Stack Exchange site graduated from Area 51?

Tags: support, area-51

Is there a way to know what date a Stack Exchange site went live? In other words what date it graduated from Area 51 to full-fledged status?

Comment: Do you want to know the exact date? Also, why not visit the meta of the site you have in mind?

Comment: @M.A.Ramezani Yes, I would like to know the exact date. Do you mean there is a property for this visible somewhere on the meta for each site? Can you tell me where?

Comment: @GaryBarrett I think the idea was to ask a question on the per-site meta; the people at that site are more likely to know than the people here.

Answer (score 5):

You can get the time the site went live (beta) by visit the proposal page on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) and putting your mouse pointer over the description of "public beta start" or "private beta start" (whichever you're more interested in) and you'll get a tooltip with the exact date and time. <sup>1</sup>

For instance, this is from the [Biology proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12502/biology):

[image: screen shot with tool tip]

As for full graduation (with a custom design and everything) that's almost always [announced on the site's Meta](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3033/site-graduated). I'd search for "graduated" or "new design" to find the announcement post.

---

<sup>1</sup> This is generally true of any relative time string ("3 years ago", "1 hour ago", "last month") on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 3):

You can get this information using the [Stack Exchange API](http://api.stackexchange.com/). This is what my page [timeline of SE sites](http://dropproxy.com/f/A62) does.